# Add multiple sets of named elements to array in one syntax in Php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $products and I this is how i add elements to it.

```
$products[] = ['name'=>'prod1', 'qty'=>'5', 'price'=>'20'];
$products[] = ['name'=>'prod2', 'qty'=>'10', 'price'=>'30'];
$products[] = ['name'=>'prod3', 'qty'=>'15', 'price'=>'40'];
```

My question is, is there a way to add all three sets of elements in a single syntax. for example:

```
$products[] = ['name'=>'prod1', 'qty'=>'5', 'price'=>'20'],
              ['name'=>'prod2', 'qty'=>'10', 'price'=>'30'],
              ['name'=>'prod3', 'qty'=>'15', 'price'=>'40'];
```

Comment: that's wrong code

Comment: All you can do is to use `array_merge`, but to use it, you need to create an array with the new items you want to add. I'm not sure it is interesting.

Comment: But I don't think it is a better way than adding items one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Example:

```
array_push($products, 
  ['name'=>'prod1', 'qty'=>'5', 'price'=>'20'],
  ['name'=>'prod2', 'qty'=>'10', 'price'=>'30'],
  ['name'=>'prod3', 'qty'=>'15', 'price'=>'40']
);
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61dcf66e1b6f8acceaf5bcf83fe1d1c6be42fba4)